# gdb does NOT seem work when I am doing experiment with xv6

Tags: c

Currently I'm doing some exercise on xv6 book, but I intend to debug with gdb, I found something not working... On one terminal it is listening to 25000, seems ok

```
~/xv6-labs-2020# make qemu-gdb
*** Now run 'gdb' in another window.
qemu-system-riscv64 -machine virt -bios none -kernel kernel/kernel -m 128M -smp 3 -nographic -drive file=fs.img,if=none,format=raw,id=x0 -device virtio-blk-device,drive=x0,bus=virtio-mmio-bus.0 -S -gdb tcp::25000
```

It seems something is broken, but I really have no idea and could not continue... could anyone help? thx!

```
(gdb) target remote:25000
Remote debugging using :25000
warning: Architecture rejected target-supplied description
warning: No executable has been specified and target does not support
determining executable automatically.  Try using the "file" command.
Truncated register 37 in remote 'g' packet
(gdb) b _entry
No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) y
Breakpoint 1 (_entry) pending.
(gdb) r
Starting program:
No executable file specified.
Use the "file" or "exec-file" command.
(gdb) file kernel/kernel
Reading symbols from kernel/kernel...done.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /root/xv6-labs-2020/kernel/kernel
/bin/bash: /root/xv6-labs-2020/kernel/kernel: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
/bin/bash: /root/xv6-labs-2020/kernel/kernel: Success
During startup program exited with code 126.
(gdb)
```

Comment: The GDB command for continue is `c`.

Comment: when I type c, it says `The program is not being run.` so I typed start or run

Comment: Did you use the GDB for the target architecture? The GDB for your development system cannot work.

Comment: thx for reply, this is my remote server, not my local machine, `Linux  4.14.129-bbrplus #1 SMP Mon Jun 24 16:51:05 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux` this is the version, I'm doing test about qemu, is there any problem with my machine? or I need another gdb, I spend a lot of time on this problem...

Answer (score 0):

Try using riscv64-unknown-elf-gdb or riscv64-linux-gnu-gdb.